# Creating a remote project with PyDev

Tags: python, pydev

I'm new to Eclipse/PyDev and have what's probably a really basic question.  I want to use it to edit and debug python files on a remote system.  I am able to do this using RSE and pydevd, but what I'm doing doesn't really seem integrated with the IDE.  That is, I can go to the RSE perspective and edit the files.  I can then lauch the script on the remote system and step through it in the debugger.  But the files are not part of a project that Eclipse maintains for me.  It's all fairly disjointed.  Is there a way to make remote files part of an Eclipse project?  I can drag the files into the project, but that makes a local copy.  Am I just approaching this wrong?

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 6):

OK, it turns out to be not only simple but rather obvious once you find it.  From the RSE perspective, right-click the folder containing your source files and select "Create Remote Project." This seems to work fairly well, but I'm still having one problem: It seems the debugger wants a local copy of the file I am debugging, and does not consider the RSE copy local enough. So now I have to copy the file from the remote server to my workstation before I start debugging. It kind of defeats the purpose of the integration.

Is there a better way? I'm looking at SSH filesystems, but really don't want to have to do that. It feels like I'm so close.

Edit 2011-11-09:
This has recently been addressed by the PyDev developers.  As of today, installing the nightly PyDev update adds an option to fetch source from the remote server.  Details [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3387080&group_id=85796&atid=577332).

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this issue a while back ,I answered this question in the link below. Unfortunately, with eclipse you cannot setup a remote interpreter with the RSE package. I use Pycharm ( python Jetbrains IDE). And it has been working great for me for about a year now. You do have to pay for it, its a nominal amount but worth it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15360958/1702186