# Terminal-based Python editor like IPython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, terminal, command-line-interface, jupyter-notebook

Is there anything like IPython Notebook that operates 100% in a terminal window? I would like to be able to see and edit Python code blocks, navigate between the code blocks, execute individual code blocks at will, and have output from the code blocks displayed just below each code block. Obviously stuff like `%matplotlib inline` couldn't be supported. Ideally I would be able to open a functional `*.ipynb` file with this program and work with it in the terminal window, but I would still be happy if it had a different extension that isn't compatible with IPython Notebook.

I'm interested in this because I like the IPython Notebook concept, but it can be slow when using it interactively on a remote server.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What about the IPython QtConsole?

Comment: @ρss OK, thanks for letting me know. In the future, where would you recommend I go to ask for software or library recommendations then?

Comment: @Jim I didn't know about IPython QtConsole, so thanks for bringing that up, but from a quick glance it doesn't look quite like what I want. Pretty much any GUI I use while SSH-ing into a remote machine lags a bit, including QtConsole. More importantly, it doesn't look like I can edit and re-execute previous code blocks.

Comment: @BenLindsay You can edit and re-execute by pressing the up and down arrows. Either way the only other viable solution is the plain ol' IPython interactive shell which offers less capabilities than the gui and web options but runs through the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that there is anything precisely fitting your requirements. However, the Python mode of emacs fit most of your requirements, I routinely use this to develop and debug Python on a remote server.

Another option may be to use the Remote features of PyDev if you're an Eclipse user. This is described further in another question:

[Creating a remote project with PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002534/creating-a-remote-project-with-pydev)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm a Vim user, so my solution will probably be to try to get Vim configured as a good Python IDE. I see a lot of posts that make it look doable.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of remote work you may find tmux useful, in addition to the pudb debugger (full screen terminal).  Your only problem may be viewing matplotlib output but you could redirect it to a secured web-accessible directory.

Comment: I think I'll start trying out emacs as an IDE. I've heard good things about it elsewhere.